# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'store.createRecord')

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a 'new' action within a component (Ember.Component) that has the following code in it:

```
var store = this.get('store');
store.createRecord('child');
```

yet I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'store.createRecord')
```

The only way I've been able to proceed with this is to find the parent object (always set in the component) by using:

```
store = this.get('parent.store');
```

and then proceeding with the createRecord call from above. Is this the "normal" way to proceed?

Comment: Can you display some more code? where you attempt this is extremely important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store doesn't exist inside of a component, so either you need to pass it into the component, or you have to get it from some parent controller (or passed in controller).

Via Ember Data Transition document (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)

> In general, looking up models directly in a component is an anti-pattern, and you should prefer to pass in any model you need in the template that included the component.

The bad part about it, is you are adding a dependency to ember data in your component, which is supposed to be agnostic of the outside world.

Comment: Okey dokey. That's what I thought. Thanks. So, the way I was doing it was the "proper" way to do it then :) Cool.

Comment: *The bad part about it, is you are adding a dependency to ember data in your component, which is supposed to be agnostic of the outside world.*

Yeah, I'm in the process of reworking things so they're not so dependent on the model layer anyway.

Comment: Kinda odd, but I've read that transition document about 50 times by now. I can't believe I didn't remember that. <sigh> :)

Comment: Cool so I'm now using this:

    <button {{action "new" parentObject target=actionTarget}}>New</button>

and then in the template that calls the component, I pass through the actionTarget by specifying actionTarget=this. Then I specify the new action on controller for the template where the component is called. Yay :) Thanks again.

Comment: That's how we generally do it, we pass the actions out, and allow the context outside of it to handle it.